equality involving supremum and infimum of two disjoint sets that partition the real Line
Let $A$ and $B$ two subsets of  $\mathbb{R}$ such that : $A \cup B = \mathbb{R}$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$.
We suppose that $A$ has a supremum that we denote $\alpha$ , and $B$ has an infimum that we denote $\beta$.
Show that $\alpha = \beta$
My attempt :
By definition of the sup :
$\forall \epsilon > 0 : \alpha + \epsilon \notin A$
So :
$\forall \epsilon > 0 : \alpha + \epsilon \in B \ \Longrightarrow \forall \epsilon > 0 : \alpha + \epsilon \geq b$
Hence $ \alpha \geq \beta $
I've been stuck for the past hours on how to achieve the second part of the inequality (i.e $\alpha \leq \beta$ )
Any help is appreciated.

This is not true without further hypotheses: consider $A = (-\infty, 0) \cup {1}$ (and $B = \mathbb{R} \setminus A$).

You're having trouble with this because it's false.  Let $B=\{0 \} \cup (1, \infty).$  Let $A= \Bbb R \setminus B$.  Then $\sup A=1$ but $\inf B = 0$.  For this to be true, you need the additional condition that $A$ is closed downward and $B$ is closed upward.

What does "closed downward" mean?

does that mean  B should be an interval of the form $[\gamma , +\infty)$

@AdamRubinson $A$ is closed downward if $(x \in A \land y \lt x) \Rightarrow y \in A$.
